# React Native flatlist data is not displaying

Tags: react-native

Iam using fetch API to show Flatlist data in my screen.

Here is the Json data that i am getting

```
{
    "requestDetails": "facilityList",
    "data": [
        {
            "facilityId": 73,
            "name": "ALS-ALL SAINTS HOSPITAL-NTX",
            "facilitY_PFX": "ALS",
            "isFromAllScripts": false
        },
        {
            "facilityId": 74,
            "name": "BHVH-BAYLOR HEART AND VASCULAR HOSPITAL-NTX",
            "facilitY_PFX": "BHVH",
            "isFromAllScripts": false
        },
        {
            "facilityId": 78,
            "name": "BUMC-BAYLOR UNIVERSITY MEDICAL CENTER HOSPITAL-NTX",
            "facilitY_PFX": "BUMC",
            "isFromAllScripts": false
        },
        {
            "facilityId": 79,
            "name": "CAR-CARROLLTON HOSPITAL-NTX",
            "facilitY_PFX": "CAR",
            "isFromAllScripts": true
        },
        {
            "facilityId": 81,
            "name": "DEN-TEXAS HEART HOSPITAL BAYLOR DENTON-NTX",
            "facilitY_PFX": "DEN",
            "isFromAllScripts": true
        },
]
```

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';

interface IState {
    isLoading: boolean;
    dataSource: any;
}
export default class FacilityList extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: [],
        };
        this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        return fetch(Request_url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                // just setState here e.g.
                this.setState({ dataSource: responseJson.data, isLoading: false });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <View >
              <Text  >{item.name}</Text>
              </View>
        );
      }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    touchButton: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
        paddingVertical: 25,
        width: 295,
        margin: 15,
    },
    touchButtonText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#ffffff',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
});
```

but nothing is displaying in my screen with this code, i am getting a blank screen
please let me know if there is anything wrong in my code and why the data is not getting displayed without any errors.

Update:

I am sorry, i have to pass a token in the header, after passing the token it was working fine.

Comment: can you remove **return** from **componentDidMount()** and try once.

Comment: I have removed return but still the data is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

```js
var newData = "{\"requestDetails\": \"facilityList\",\"data\": [{\"facilityId\": 73,\"name\": \"ALS-ALL SAINTS HOSPITAL-NTX\",\"facilitY_PFX\": \"ALS\",\"isFromAllScripts\": false},{\"facilityId\": 74,\"name\": \"BHVH-BAYLOR HEART AND VASCULAR HOSPITAL-NTX\",\"facilitY_PFX\": \"BHVH\",\"isFromAllScripts\": false}]}";

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(newData);
console.log(jsonObj.data[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you declare `Request_url`  somewhere? or maybe you put a link directly?

Comment: There is a URL that i have passed into fetch()

Comment: can you try with this syntax: ```renderItem={({ item }) => this. renderItem(item)}```